# What is wrong with variable?

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

I've read other questions about global variables, but my case is special.

First I declare instance variables at the starting of the class:

```
class Answers: UIViewController {
    var mystring:String!
    var mystring2:String!
```

Then I get json data via Alamofire in Swift 3:

```
let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary
if !(jsonData.value(forKey: "error") as! Bool) {
      let user = jsonData.value(forKey: "awdata") as! NSDictionary

      let question = user.value(forKey: "question") as! String
      print(question) // returns string "ABC"
      mystring = question
      mystring2 = "test"
}
```

When I use these variables in a function the variable `mystring1` returns null, but variable `mystring2` returns `"test"`:

```
func someFunc() {
      print(mystring) // returns nothing
      print(mystring2) // returns test
}
```

So why the first variable is not retaining value, but the second variable remembers?

Comment: The code is incomplete. It does not show the Alamofire related code and how (actually when) the function `someFunc()` is used. I guess your case is not special it looks like the famous *async-trap*. And – as always – do not use `NSDictionary` in Swift and `valueForKey` not at all in this context.

Comment: Instead of `NSDictionary` use native `[String:Any]`. Instead of `value(forKey` which is a KVC method use `object(forKey` or – recommended – key subscription (`jsonData["awdata"]`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to show all of the code if you want a full answer. 
I would prefix your instance variables with self to make sure you are actually dealing with the instance variable when you read or update them. I would avoid using as! because it's just bad, particularly when decoding data.